# CSS transition doesn't work with top: auto

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to modify a tutorial I found online that did 'almost' what I needed it to, but got stuck when it came to the CSS 'transitions' effects.

Essentially I need the text to be a certain space from the top, because the title will always be the same height (so only the title shows). And on hover I need the text block to be stuck to the bottom edge because the hover text could be long or short.

I have it working the way I want it to, but when I use top: auto the transition effect no longer works. If I give top a value of 0, then the text is stuck to the top and not the bottom like I want.

https://jsfiddle.net/bsummers/sxh0n7d1/

Will the transitions simply just not work with 'auto'?

```css
body{
  font-family: arial;  
}
}.showcase {
 list-style: none;
}
.showcase li {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}
.showcase li:last-child{
    margin: 0;
}
.showcase a {
    display: block;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.showcase a img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a:hover img {
 top: -20px;
}
.showcase .text-holder {
    top: 156px;
    bottom: 0;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a:hover .text-holder {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto; //changing this to 0 doesn't stick the text to the bottom, but transition works.

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a h3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="showcase">
  <li class="thumb1"> 
    <a href="http://blog.web3canvas.com/">
      <img src="http://demo.web3canvas.com/html5-css3/image-gallery-showcase-pure-css3/images/thumb1.jpg" width="500" height="374" alt="web3canvas">
      <div class="text-holder">
        <h3>My Profile<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem leo. Pellentesque et libero id lectus pretium lacinia...</span></h3>
      </div> 
    </a> 
  </li>
  
    <li class="thumb2"> 
    <a href="http://blog.web3canvas.com/">
      <img src="http://demo.web3canvas.com/html5-css3/image-gallery-showcase-pure-css3/images/thumb2.jpg" width="500" height="374" alt="web3canvas">
      <div class="text-holder">
        <h3>My Profile<span>Different length of text...</span></h3>
      </div> 
    </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What part of the fiddle is not working the way you want it to?

Comment: The transition on the text box isn't working. It's a jerky "from here to here" movement. It should slide nicely. If you change top: auto, to top: 0 you'll see the transition, but the box doesn't go where I want it to.

Comment: Can I use javacsript to fix the issue?

Comment: Or consider doing it like this https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/1/

Comment: @Scott why would you set a possible dup to a question that is neg 1 and an answer that is 0?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I guess if you think the voting actually means *anything* I can see your point. My point is that the desired effect is the same as that question.... how users have voted is largely irrelevant if the question/answer **is** relevant.

Comment: @Scott I see that it is your answer now you are pointing too, it does not answer the question of **"Will the transitions simply just not work with 'auto'?"** please explain how this is a dup?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith see my answer... All I did was take the *principals from the duplicate link* and apply them to your code. **That** is why the duplicate was relevant. You don't need "auto" anywhere.

Comment: No, it won't work. `auto` can't be interpolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the *duplicate is relevant*.

See the snippet below. This the *same* solution as provided in the duplicate link. Use `transform: translateY();` to move the overlay rather than trying to calculate constantly changing heights.

```css
body{
  font-family: arial;  
}
}.showcase {
 list-style: none;
}
.showcase li {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}
.showcase li:last-child{
    margin: 0;
}
.showcase a {
    display: block;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.showcase a img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a:hover img {
 top: -20px;
}
.showcase .text-holder {
    top: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;

  transform: translateY(-50px); /* Height you want shown at load */

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a:hover .text-holder {
    top: 100%;
  
   transform: translateY(-100%); /* moves 100% of the overlay into view. */
  
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.showcase a h3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="showcase">
  <li class="thumb1"> 
    <a href="http://blog.web3canvas.com/">
      <img src="http://demo.web3canvas.com/html5-css3/image-gallery-showcase-pure-css3/images/thumb1.jpg" width="500" height="374" alt="web3canvas">
      <div class="text-holder">
        <h3>My Profile<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem leo. Pellentesque et libero id lectus pretium lacinia...</span></h3>
      </div> 
    </a> 
  </li>
  
    <li class="thumb2"> 
    <a href="http://blog.web3canvas.com/">
      <img src="http://demo.web3canvas.com/html5-css3/image-gallery-showcase-pure-css3/images/thumb2.jpg" width="500" height="374" alt="web3canvas">
      <div class="text-holder">
        <h3>My Profile<span>Different length of text...</span></h3>
      </div> 
    </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

"auto" often fails with transitions because "auto" is *not* a value. You can't transition from a *value* to an ambiguous setting.

> Not every CSS property can be transitioned, and the basic rule is that you can only transition through absolute values. For example, you can’t transition between a height of 0px to auto. The browser can’t calculate the intermediate transition values, so the property change is instant.
>   **Taken from: https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions**

Comment: it solves the problem but still does not answer this question "Will the transitions simply just not work with 'auto'?"

Comment: My point is by googling the question or searching for it on SO, it does not show. Making it a dup is simply ridiculous.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get to this until now, this solution worked for me. I will be using translateY from now on :)